# Getting only border-bottom in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I wanted only border-bottom line, not border-left, border-right or border-top:
So I wrote a code like this:
**`CSS code`** and **`HTML code`**:

```css
.category {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 33px;
  margin: 2% 0;
  padding: 1% 2%;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: lined;
  border-bottom-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class = "category">
  <span class = "ctgryName" id="ctgryName">JNCIA - Junos</span>
  <!-- <span class = "ctgryIcon pull-right"></span> -->
</div>
```

But I'm getting a whole border, I want only border-bottom line.
How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried changing `border: 1px solid blue` to `border-bottom: 1px solid blue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
border: 1px solid bleu;
```

to

```
 border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can select wich border you want to display like this :

```
border:0;
border-bottom:1px solid blue;
```

Answer (score 2):

> Your mistake is that you set the `border` instead of `border-bottom`, please do the following-

change this css line:

```
border: 1px solid blue;
```

to

```
border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code..
u made mistake in css
you have used border also and border-bottom also. u need to use only border-bottom

```
   .category {
   border-radius: 4px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
   height: 33px;
   margin: 2% 0;
   padding: 1% 2%;
   width: 100%;

    }
```